# Position Label In Center Without Filling The Entire Layout in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, qvboxlayout

I'm creating an app in PyQt5 and I want my label to be in the center of the window, without it filling the entire space. So `Some Label` should be where `Hello` is as seen below, but I don't want `Some Label` to fill up the entire space.

[image]

I thought perhaps I could put `Some Label` in a container that fills up the entire space, and center `Some Label` inside the container just like `Hello`, but I just can't get this to work.

Here's my code:

```
def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = QWidget()

    win.setFixedSize(225,150)

    label1 = QLabel("Hello")
    label1.setStyleSheet('border: 1px solid red')

    label2 = QLabel("Some Label", label1)
    label2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    label2.setStyleSheet('background: red')

    label1.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

    layout = QVBoxLayout()
    layout.addWidget(label1)

    win.setLayout(layout)

    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

main()
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I suppose that by "So `Some Label` should be where `Hello` is" you only mean horizontally, so that you'll have a vertical rectangle that only fills the required horizontal space for those two labels? And why you're adding a second label as a child of the first? Note that QLabels are quite peculiar widgets, and adding children (including layouts) to them may not be reliable, especially for display purposes.

Comment: @musicamante I wanted label1 to serve as a container (which IS allowed to expand to full size), and then center label2 within. Centering only label1 obviously causes it to expand to the size of the parent (window), which I dont want. The answer by mahkitah works fine for me tho.

Comment: Ok, so your `label1` was just an attempt, you were only interested in how `label2` (the one displaying "Some Label") would be placed. That wasn't very clear. For future reference, whenever you need a widget container, just use QWidget or eventually QFrame, as QLabel is not really suited for that purpose (and its usage may lead to confusion).

Comment: @musicamante Well, how am i supposed to show where i want the text to be at then? How more clear than ‘how can i center-align a label without it filling the entire space’ could a question be? Anyways i got the answer, so no need to argue about it. Thanks

Comment: I'm not arguing, I'm pointing out that if the code of a question leads to misunderstanding, it can be a further problem to *two* categories of people: those that may want to help you (so you may not receive valid answers, or you have to wait for them much more), and anybody that could be facing a very similar problem and may dismiss the post because they don't think it relates to their cases (or they are mislead by it believing that it does, while it doesn't). A common, simpler and more reliable solution in these cases it to create a mock up of the wanted result using a basic drawing program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to set the alignment on the layout:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

app = QApplication([])
win = QWidget()
win.setFixedSize(225, 150)

label1 = QLabel("Hello")
label1.setStyleSheet('border: 1px solid red')

layout = QVBoxLayout(win)
layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
layout.addWidget(label1)

win.show()
app.exec()
```

Comment: Thanks! Couldn't find this anywhere

Comment: Actually, the same could be achieved by adding the `alignment` argument of [`addWidget()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qboxlayout.html#addWidget): "The default alignment is 0, which means that the widget fills the entire cell". This is also normally the preferred choice, as it allows to specify the alignment for a specific item, so that any other item can have its own alignment (if any).